# reset_counters is failing on exisitng and new projects

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Ok..I hope I am doing something dumb (which is usually the case). I have been humming along, adding cache counters to my existing project, when all of the sudden reset_counters failed for pretty much everything. I checked out an old copy when things were working, and it still failed, so I started on a brand new demo project.

I assume this is my error because it suddenly stopped working..and I don't see anyone else having similar issues.
I am using ruby 1.9.3-p392, and rails 3.2.12.

The counters themselves work on both existing and new projects. you just can't use reset_counters.

So here is the problem on a brand new project:

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :name
  has_many :comments
end


class Comment < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :name
  belongs_to :post, :counter_cache => true
end
```

here we can see the counters increment:

```
irb(main):073:0* post = Post.create(:name => 'i am a post')
   (0.3ms)  BEGIN
  SQL (0.4ms)  INSERT INTO `posts` (`comments_count`, `created_at`, `name`, `updated_at`) VALUES (0, '2013-03-14 19:56:53', 'i am a post', '2013-03-14 19:56:53')
   (0.5ms)  COMMIT
=> #<Post id: 3, name: "i am a post", created_at: "2013-03-14 19:56:53", updated_at: "2013-03-14 19:56:53", comments_count: 0>
irb(main):074:0> post.comments << Comment.new(:name => 'i am a comment')
   (0.2ms)  BEGIN
  SQL (0.3ms)  INSERT INTO `comments` (`created_at`, `name`, `post_id`, `updated_at`) VALUES ('2013-03-14 19:57:18', 'i am a comment', 3, '2013-03-14 19:57:18')
  Post Load (0.3ms)  SELECT `posts`.* FROM `posts` WHERE `posts`.`id` = 3 LIMIT 1
  SQL (0.3ms)  UPDATE `posts` SET `comments_count` = COALESCE(`comments_count`, 0) + 1 WHERE `posts`.`id` = 3
   (0.4ms)  COMMIT
  Comment Load (0.2ms)  SELECT `comments`.* FROM `comments` WHERE `comments`.`post_id` = 3
=> [#<Comment id: 3, name: "i am a comment", post_id: 3, created_at: "2013-03-14 19:57:18", updated_at: "2013-03-14 19:57:18">]
irb(main):075:0> post = Post.find(3)
  Post Load (0.5ms)  SELECT `posts`.* FROM `posts` WHERE `posts`.`id` = 3 LIMIT 1
=> #<Post id: 3, name: "i am a post", created_at: "2013-03-14 19:56:53", updated_at: "2013-03-14 19:56:53", comments_count: 1>
```

running the code I get:

```
irb(main):001:0> Post.reset_counters(1,:comments_count)
  Post Load (0.5ms)  SELECT `posts`.* FROM `posts` WHERE `posts`.`id` = 1 LIMIT 1
NoMethodError: undefined method `options' for nil:NilClass
    from /Users/charles/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p392/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.12/lib/active_record/counter_cache.rb:22:in `block in reset_counters'
    from /Users/charles/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p392/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.12/lib/active_record/counter_cache.rb:19:in `each'
    from /Users/charles/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p392/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.12/lib/active_record/counter_cache.rb:19:in `reset_counters'
    from (irb):1
    from /Users/charles/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p392/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.12/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:47:in `start'
    from /Users/charles/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p392/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.12/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:8:in `start'
    from /Users/charles/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p392/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.12/lib/rails/commands.rb:41:in `<top (required)>'
    from script/rails:6:in `require'
    from script/rails:6:in `<main>'
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're almost entirely correct.  The parameter in `reset_counters` though should be the object name, not the column name.  So in your case you want to:

```
1.9.3-p392 :005 > Post.reset_counters(1, :comments)
  Post Load (0.3ms)  SELECT "posts".* FROM "posts" WHERE "posts"."id" = ? LIMIT 1  [["id", 1]]
   (0.1ms)  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "comments" WHERE "comments"."post_id" = 1
   (2.3ms)  UPDATE "posts" SET "comments_count" = 1 WHERE "posts"."id" = 1
 => true
```

Comment: `reset_counters` is now deprecated

Comment: not deprecated, moved to http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/CounterCache/ClassMethods/reset_counters